# jinja conditional statements rendered in HTML page

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Here is the HTML I wrote for a flask app, the problem here is when I load the page in chrome I'm getting the jinja conditions as it is from the HTML. I have added an image for better understanding, Any help? Thanks!

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost:5000/math" method="POST">
            <h2>Function:</h2>
            <p>
                <input type="number" name = "v1">
                <input type="number" name ="v2">
                <select id="fun" name="math">
                    <option value="addNumbers">ADD</option>
                    <option value="subtractNumbers">SUB</option>
                    <option value="multiplyNumbers">MUL</option>
                    <option value="divideNumbers">DIV</option>
                    <option value="modulusNumbers">MOD</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <input type="submit" value="Process">
        </form>

        {% if value %}
            <h2>The {{proc}} of {{a}} and {{b}} is {{value}}</h2>
        {% else %}
            <h2>Please enter the fields right</h2>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

HTML rendered:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you say that you load the page in Chrome, it sounds like you are accessing the page directly without running the flask app that would render your jinja template. Is that the case? Because that's exactly what would make your page look the way it does. If so, check your page with the app running.

Comment: Hey, thanks! the issue was in the .py script I left if condition without adding else, so there was no otherwise and default value for variables were considered.

Answer (score 0):

There might be few reasons why this is not working.

1. check if jinja is installed
2. check If html file is in template folder
3. Try changing your ide or run flask app from windows cmd.
   if any of these are not the issues than can you give the code so that I can test on my machine.

Comment: Thanks man! The 3 point helped the Flask app was running on a different port.